# JS error with sliding header layout

Tags: javascript, sliding

I intent to create a simple layout with a fullscreen header that slides up to reveal a content area with an image grid. However it fails to even slide up when I click the trigger, and I think most likely the error occurs in my java script,http://jsfiddle.net/LwLyht51/ here's my js:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
(function() {
            var container = document.getElementById( 'container' ),
                trigger = container.querySelector( 'button.trigger' );

            function toggleContent() {
                if( classie.has( container, 'container--open' ) ) {
                    classie.remove( container, 'container--open' );
                    classie.remove( trigger, 'trigger--active' );
                    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', noscroll );
                }
                else {
                    classie.add( container, 'container--open' );
                    classie.add( trigger, 'trigger--active' );
                    window.removeEventListener( 'scroll', noscroll );
                }
            }

            function noscroll() {
                window.scrollTo( 0, 0 );
            }

            // reset scrolling position
            document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

            // disable scrolling
            window.addEventListener( 'scroll', noscroll );

            trigger.addEventListener( 'click', toggleContent );


        })();

</script>
```

Update of Codes of classie.js:

```
/*!
* classie - class helper functions
* from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
*
* classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
* classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
* classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
* classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
*/

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
return elem.classList.contains( c );
};
addClass = function( elem, c ) {
elem.classList.add( c );
};
removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
elem.classList.remove( c );
};
}
else {
hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
};
addClass = function( elem, c ) {
if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
  elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
}
};
removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
};
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
// full names
hasClass: hasClass,
addClass: addClass,
removeClass: removeClass,
toggleClass: toggleClass,
// short names
has: hasClass,
add: addClass,
remove: removeClass,
toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
// AMD
define( classie );
} else {
// browser global
window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

Comment: `classie` variable is not defined in the function, first check your browser console for errors by using `F12` key

Comment: @tzafar Hi I have just updated my classie.js file codes

Comment: define the trigger variable with `var` keyword, like `var trigger = container.querySelector( 'button.trigger' );` and try or use someother name for trigger variable as it is also used for function  or reserved word in js i think

Comment: @tzafar I thought on line 4 of my js I already defined it?

Comment: yeah sorry my mistake, i am testing your code and if found anything helpful then i will add here

Comment: @tzafar Really appreciate it, and I just update with jsfiddle of my project, hope it will be of help.

Comment: i have tested your code in chrome and its working fine, check it on chrome and also remove `slash` from body start tag `<body  style=" width: 480px; height: 800px; margin:0;">`

Comment: @tzafar I was testing it in chrome and when you click on trigger, the image grid will come out?

Comment: yeah when we click on the trigger button, the header slideup and image grid come up, check your fiddlejs demo by removing `var` from  starting of your `trigger = container.querySelector( 'button.trigger' );`

Comment: @tzafar Wow, this excites me though mine still not works:( Is it possible to send me the jsfiddle u r using? Since Idk why mine just fails to slide up.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/bmhu0q02/ or try it with another browser as i think your js script is loading from browser cache

Comment: @tzafar dk why still doesn't work, or maybe should I clean cache first?

Comment: yeah try to remove the cache first and then try it as i have checked the jsfiddle demo on IE and its working there also, and also add all the code in the one file and try it.

Comment: Ok no problem, try last thing chrome `clear cache and hard refresh option` , check here http://www.code-pal.com/quick-tip-clear-cache-hard-refresh-on-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

If someone still look for this error (like me)

just add **id** "container" in your code

var container = document.**getElementById**( 'container' )